# what's the correct way destroy different kinds of objects in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, object, destroy

I have this object that contains references to other objects:
1)views
2)view controllers
3)dictionaries
4)arrays
5)custom objects.
what's the best way to destroy it? do I need to create a destroy method that will deal with the destruction of its different properties?
are there special things to be done in each one of these types or I just set them all to nil?

note: I am using ARC.

thanks,
Nimrod

Comment: destroy means release from memory after use?

Comment: You don't "destroy" any Objective-C objects.  Rather, you (somehow) decrement their reference counts to zero and let them be delete.

Comment: `*(char*)0x42 = 'b';` you destroyed it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether you use [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) or not.

Without ARC you have to override the dealloc method and release the objects you own.

With ARC you can just set your main object to `nil`. ARC will take care of releasing the object and all of the other objects it owns.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ARC, You dont need to bother much about the releasing the objects, Unless there is some Retain Cycle.

You can send nil to your object as `yourObject=nil;` that will make it nil and will be released later on.

Comment: @NimrodYizhar: So what you want? Even when you dont set it to `nil`, at the end of event loop, all will go to autorelease pool and will get released/destroyed.